# Difference in days between multiple states

Tags: sql, oracle

I am working with ORACLE SQL and I have encountered a problem i have a difficult time solving.

In my system users can make orders of products. These orders can be in different states: `WAITING`, `ACCEPTED`, `IN_PROGRESS`, `DELIVERED`, `REMOVED`, `DELETED`. 
These orders are logged in a table called tblorderlog.

The table contains the columns: `OrderId`, `OrderState`, and `OrderStateDate`.

I want to find the difference in days between the `OrderStateDates`, but the problem is that not every order goes through every orderstate, so one order might only go from `WAITING`, `DELIVERED`, and `REMOVED`.
Is there a way to calculate the days between the states no matter the order of the states?

What I have done:

```
select distinct susu.orderid, ol.orderstatedate,  ol.orderstate,
case
when ol.orderstate =  'WAITING' then null 
when ol.orderstate =  'ACCEPTED' then round(tblaccepted.orderstatedate- 
tblwaiting,0)
when ol.orderstate =  'IN_PROGRESS' then round(tblinprogress.orderstatedate-tblaccepted.orderstatedate,0)
when ol.orderstate = 'DELIVERED' then round(tbldelivered.orderstatedate-tblinprogress.orderstatedate,0)
when ol.orderstate =  'REMOVED' then round(tblremoved.orderstatedate-tbldelivered.orderstatedate,0)
when ol.orderstate = 'DELETED' then round(tbldeleted.orderstatedate-tblremoved.orderstatedate,0)
else -10 --(Random number)
end as days_between_orderstates
from tblsusu susu
left join tblorderlog ol on susu.orderid = ol.orderid
left join (select ol.orderid, ol.orderstatedate
       from tblorderlog ol
       where ol.orderstate = 'WAITING') tblwaiting on susu.orderid = tblwaiting.orderid 
left join (select ol.orderid, ol.orderstatedate
       from tblorderlog ol
       where ol.orderstate = 'ACCEPTED') tblaccepted on susu.orderid = tblaccepted.orderid 
left join (select ol.orderid, ol.orderstatedate
       from tblorderlog ol
       where ol.orderstate = 'IN_PROGRESS') tblinprogress on susu.orderid = tblinprogress.orderid 
left join (select ol.orderid, ol.orderstatedate
       from tblorderlog ol
       where ol.orderstate = 'DELIVERED') tbldelivered on susu.orderid = tbldelivered.orderid 
left join (select ol.orderid, ol.orderstatedate
       from tblorderlog ol
       where ol.orderstate = 'REMOVED') tblremoved on susu.orderid = tblremoved.orderid 
left join (select ol.orderid, ol.orderstatedate
       from tblorderlog ol
       where ol.orderstate = 'DELETED') tbldeleted on susu.orderid = tbldeleted.orderid 
order by susu.orderid, ol.orderstatedate
```

I want output like:

```
orderid    orderstate        orderdate     days_between_order_states
21          WAITING          22/07/18              NULL (or empty)
21          ACCPETED         24/07/18              2
21          DELIVERED        25/07/18              1
21          REMOVED          25/07/18              0
21          DELETED          26/07/18              1
25          WAITING          01/08/18              NULL (or empty)
25          DELIVERED        05/08/18              4
25          DELETED          06/08/18              1
..
..
```

Comment: The states can be in any order, not just that some can be skipped? Can they be repeated? Please include some representative sample data and expected results in your question (as formatted text, not images).

Comment: You definitely don't need that many left joins to the same table (`tblorderlog`) add just one and in your case expression you use its alias with the `orderstate` column.

Comment: @JorgeCampos, can you please show an example?

Comment: When you add information in your question as @AlexPoole asked, I may.

Comment: @AlexPoole thanks for the edit, i am a bit new here. But this is the expected output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are really only looking for each order state and the number of days since the previous state, whatever that was, then you don't really case about each state value - you only case about the order that the states change.

You can use the `lag()` analytic function to look at a previous row, where you define what 'previous' means in the `over()` clause; here you want the row for the same order ID with the most recent state change date.

As a starting point you can look at something like :

```
select susu.orderid, ol.orderstatedate, ol.orderstate,
  lag(ol.orderstatedate)
    over (partition by susu.orderid order by ol.orderstatedate) as prev_orderstatedate,
  lag(ol.orderstate)
    over (partition by susu.orderid order by ol.orderstatedate) as prev_orderstate,
  round(ol.orderstatedate - lag(ol.orderstatedate)
    over (partition by susu.orderid order by ol.orderstatedate))
    as days_between_orderstates
from tblsusu susu
join tblorderlog ol on ol.orderid = susu.orderid
order by susu.orderid, ol.orderstatedate;
```

For each order log entry it will show that state and its date; and the previous state and date found via `lag()`; and will calculate the difference between the current and previous times.

Based on the output you added to the question, and inferring the original data from that and supplying as two CTEs (and skipping the `prev_` values you don't want):

```
with tblsusu (orderid) as (
            select 21 from dual
  union all select 25 from dual
), tblorderlog (orderid, orderstate, orderstatedate) as (
            select 21, 'WAITING', date '2018-07-22' from dual
  union all select 21, 'ACCPETED', date '2018-07-24' from dual
  union all select 21, 'DELIVERED', date '2018-07-25' from dual
  union all select 21, 'REMOVED', date '2018-07-25' from dual
  union all select 21, 'DELETED', date '2018-07-26' from dual
  union all select 25, 'WAITING', date '2018-08-01' from dual
  union all select 25, 'DELIVERED', date '2018-08-05' from dual
  union all select 25, 'DELETED', date '2018-08-06' from dual
)
select susu.orderid, ol.orderstatedate, ol.orderstate,
  round(ol.orderstatedate - lag(ol.orderstatedate)
    over (partition by susu.orderid order by ol.orderstatedate))
    as days_between_orderstates
from tblsusu susu
join tblorderlog ol on ol.orderid = susu.orderid
order by susu.orderid, ol.orderstatedate;

   ORDERID ORDERSTATE ORDERSTATE DAYS_BETWEEN_ORDERSTATES
---------- ---------- ---------- ------------------------
        21 2018-07-22 WAITING                            
        21 2018-07-24 ACCPETED                          2
        21 2018-07-25 DELIVERED                         1
        21 2018-07-25 REMOVED                           0
        21 2018-07-26 DELETED                           1
        25 2018-08-01 WAITING                            
        25 2018-08-05 DELIVERED                         4
        25 2018-08-06 DELETED                           1
```

You may not even need the join between the tables if you aren't getting any columns except the order ID from `tblsusu`, since that is in both tables anyway.